# get file size and line count at the same time

Tags: linux, ls, stat, wc

I'm looking for a way to list all files in a directory, with both their size, and a line count. Right now I'm using `stat -c \"%s %n\" /directory/*` to get file names and sizes, and I know I can use `find /directory/ -type f -exec wc -l {} +` to get file name and line count, but is there any way I can get both at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
find directory -type f -exec wc -lc {} +
```

will get file name, line count, *and **c**haracter count*.

Strictly speaking, `-c` (a.k.a. `--bytes`) is documented as counting *bytes*,
which is probably what you want.  
There is also a `-m` (a.k.a. `--chars`) option for counting “characters”. 
From the choice of the **`m`** option letter, I guess this counts multi-byte characters;
e.g., Unicode characters. 
There is also a `-w` option for actually counting words.

Comment: Yes, this is it! I can't believe I totally missed -c, thanks!

Comment: can we print the sizes in MB ?

Answer (score 2):

`wc` can provide both byte and line counts:

```
find /directory/ -type f -exec wc -l -c {} +
```

Using `find` is also preferable to a wildcard argument (`stat ... directory/*`), because the latter will fail when there are too many files in the directory for the names to fit in a single command.

Answer (score 1):

we can simply exexute the following command in the directory

```
wc -lc *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 'find \directory-name\ -type f'
do
echo "Printing line count and size of $i"
cat $i | wc -l
du -sh $i
done
```

I think this will help you in getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
wc -c -l file1 file2 ...
```

answers must be >= 30 characters long :)

Comment: The approved technique for meeting the minimum character count (ironic!) requirement is to _explain_ your answer.